Book involving a boy who was playing Dungeons & Dragons style game and a parallel universe
I can't remember the title of this book or the author. I know it was a young adult book.
The main character was a boy who was playing a Dungeons & Dragons style game (I'll make it clear that it was not Dungeons & Dragons, but it was a similar style). The boy had his own character and eventually found out his character was real when he saw him in a bathroom or some sort of room. I think I remember a slight detail of the odd character jumping through a window of some sort.
I also remember a girl being involved and eventually a fight happens where an evil octopus character comes in. My memory is very faded.
It’s not a series. The cover also had a part on it that said something similar to "A Teen's Guide," "A Teen Boy's Guide," or "A Boy's Guide."

In roughly which year did you read this?

Possibly Spirits and Spells by Bruce Coville as per Story Identification: Young adult novel, horror, teens play a D&D variant, but things start to turn real

Trying out their new haunted house game, Sprits and Spells, in the creaky old Gulbrandsen place seemed like a cool idea to Travis, Tansy and their friends.

It does involve a stuffed octopus in the basement, used as a prompt for the game, that comes alive and speaks to them. Other parts of the plot include them finding that there's the ghost of a murdered maid in the house, and that the figures that are possessing them are actually inter-dimensional criminals from the fantasy realm their game addresses.
However, I have not found any cover with any mention of a "Guide".
  
